# Unzip a zip file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a small project,
I would like to write a program to unzip the ZIP files and display(extract) the files. Do you have a code that can do it? Here is my code that I try with the ZipFile object, but I encountered an error showing ZipFile is not defined.

Thank you

```js
  var doneReading = function(zip){
    DoSomethingWithEntries(zip);
     };

        var zipFile = new ZipFile(url, doneReading);
        function DoSomethingWithEntries(zip){ 
  //for each entry in the zip...
  for (var i=0; i<zip.entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = zip.entries[i];
    var entryInfo = "<h4><a>" + entry.name + "</a></h4>\n<div>";  
    //put that into a div, if you like.
    //etc...
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Wait until someone uploads *42.zip*.

Comment: Use a library like https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/ to unzip things.